Visual studio compiler strips lot of used global functions for some reason
i spent entire day trying to understand why parsing of my pb graph isn't working.
The parser code is looking for registered nodes / extensions.
Registration happen in global functions of each class like this:
PROTOBUF_ATTRIBUTE_INIT_PRIORITY2 static ::std::false_type
static_init2 PROTOBUF_UNUSED =
(::_pbi::AddDescriptors(&descriptor_table_mediapipe_2fframework_2ftool_2fswitch_5fcontainer_2eproto),
::_pbi::ExtensionSet::RegisterMessageExtension(
&::mediapipe::CalculatorOptions::default_instance(), 345967970, 11,
false, false, &::mediapipe::SwitchContainerOptions::default_instance(),
nullptr, ::_pbi::LazyAnnotation::kUndefined),
::std::false_type{});
Here _pbi::AddDescriptors just registers my node in global factory. And the same should happen for hundreds proto files.
But problem is - majority of my classes which should be globally registered - just stripped from the build.
So about 90% of nodes just not registered. That's why proto graph parser fails to parse the nodes.
As workaround i can create dummy instances of those node classes directly in main function, so compiler doesn't strip it.
Like this way:
mediapipe::SwitchContainerOptions* opt = new mediapipe::SwitchContainerOptions;
But this is very stupid workaround, and since i have hundreds nodes - i cannot manually instantiate all of them (and this will look ugly).
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and compile Debug build without any optimizations.
P.S. Several years ago when i implemented particles system with the same approach - i had exactly same issue, when particle features didn't registered globally because of code / classes stripping. So i had to create dummy particles features manually to avoid stripping. Those times i used Visual Studio 2013. So in 6 years nothing changed. Why Visual Studio linker decides to strip the code which is obviously 100% used by the executable code? Even in debug build!

I turns out it just strips everything. And in most cases i even cannot make any workarounds by creating dummy instances. Because there are no headers for most of graph node classes.
They just defined in cpp files:
class SwitchContainer : public Subgraph {
public:
SwitchContainer() = default;
absl::StatusOr GetConfig(const Subgraph::SubgraphOptions& options) override;
};
REGISTER_MEDIAPIPE_GRAPH(SwitchContainer);
And all them are stripped from the build. Absolutely ridiculous!!!

Self-registration schemes generally don't work. Yes, you have a static variable whose initializer calls those registration functions. But the static variable itself is not referenced anywhere, so the linker can drop it, together with its initializer, and then drop those registration functions that are no longer called.
